# SSRS parameter - Upload text file?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

HI,

Can you upload a file as part of sql server reporting service 2008 parameter?

I would like to be able to upload a text file list contract ids and produce a report based on those contracts. 
e.g for these 100 contracts what date were they entered into the system.

I could have a parameter field which takes a list of comma separated contract id's. But that will be a very hard sell.

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you feel like I answered your question, please accept it.  If not, could you give me a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmmm
I wouldn't / haven't done it, but what you might be able to do is set the report source to a sql clr table valued function, which takes as a parameter a full path and file name, then parses out the data?

- [Looks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc655659%28SQL.90%29.aspx#ssrsndtbevldfnct_topic5) like this can be done.
- Here is an [article](http://www32.brinkster.com/srisamp/sqlArticles/article_46.htm) I used when learning clr tvfs.

---

Then, according to your comments, what I would do is take the csv of ints and pass it to a sproc.  The sproc would then turn the csv into a temporary table using a table valued function.  The table produced by the table valued function would then be used in your query.  I would avoid this entire scenario if I could.  If you can provide the user with list of valid parameter choices, so much the better.  Or if that csv is a regular, slowly changing list, perhaps it is better to make it a separate report.  SSRS allows you to 'copy' or 'link' ( i forget the term ) to base/master reports.  All you're really doing is changing the set of input parameters.  The basics of the report remain the same.

See:

- [here](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)
- [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821054/how-can-i-join-on-a-csv-varchar)

Good LUCK!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would require users placing the file in network share. I think the preferred option will be have a parameter field which takes comma separated contract id's and split it. Thanks again